# How can I lock a single row in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, row, locked

It seems simple but I struggle with it. The question is how can I lock for example a single row from the table **JOBS** with **JOB_ID = IT_PROG**. I want to do it, because I want to try an exception from a procedure, where it displays you a message when you try to update a locked row. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may lock the record as described in other answers, but you will **not see any exception** while UPDATEing this row.

The `UPDATE` statement will **wait until the lock will be released**, i.e. the session  with `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` commits. After that the UPDATE will be performed.

The only exeption you can manage is DEADLOCK, i.e.

```
Session1   SELECT FOR UPDATE record A
Session2   SELECT FOR UPDATE record B
Session1   UPDATE record B  --- wait as record locked
Session2   UPDATE record A  --- deadlock as 1 is waiting on 2 and 2 waiting on 1
```

Comment: That gets an exclusive row lock.  Is there any way to "manually" get a shared row lock that is maintained for the transaction?

Comment: You may [lock the whole table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/LOCK-TABLE.html#GUID-4C00C6D9-C5C5-46CC-AD33-A64001744A4C) in *shared mode*

Comment: OK, any way to lock just a row in shared mode?

Comment: Not I'm aware of. But try to explain why you do need it. Oracle is known that the *readers* **do not block** the *writers* which you somehow try to achieve @PatrickSzalapski

Comment: Right, I am saying that I want a certain insert operation to block readers till it is committed. I know it wouldn't block other rows in the table from being read, but it would block aggregates that include the new uncommitted row.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski Uncommitted changes are not visible to sessions except for the session that made the changes (this includes other sessions by the same user); therefore if you insert a row but do not commit it then other sessions cannot read that new row and will not include it in aggregations.

Answer (score 3):

AskTom has an example of what you're trying to do:

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4515126525609

From AskTom:

```
    declare
            resource_busy   exception;
            pragma exception_init( resource_busy, -54 );
            success boolean := False;
    begin

        for i in 1 .. 3
        loop
             exit when (success);
             begin
                         select xxx from yyy where .... for update NOWAIT;
                         success := true;
             exception
                         when resource_busy then
                                 dbms_lock.sleep(1);
             end;
         end loop;

         if ( not success ) then
                     raise_application_error( -20001, 'row is locked by another session' );
         end if;
    end;
```

This attempts to get a lock, and if it can't get one (i.e. ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired is raised) it will raise an error.

Comment: Ye, thank you for the answer. I already done the PRAGMA exception. I only need to lock a single row to see if the PRAGMA actually works.

Comment: Understood. the select for update will lock a single row if your select statement returns a single row. Either give it the unique ID or a the rowid of what you want to lock.

Answer (score -2):

It's not possible to manually lock a row in Oracle. You can manually lock an object,though. Exclusive lock is placed on the  row  automatically when performing DML operations to ensure that no other sessions could update the same row or any other DDL operations could drop that row-  other sessions can read it any time.

The first session to request the lock on the rows gets it and any other sessions requesting write access must wait.
If you don't want to be get locked ,that means , if you don't want to wait , you can use

`Select .... For update ( nowait / wait(n) ) ( skiplocked)`  statement

Comment: Your first sentence is extremely misleading if not flat-out wrong.  I recommend you clarify or delete your answer if you don't want downvotes.