# How can i rewrite this lock (FOR UPDATE) subquery in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

The following query is valid in postgres.

```
SELECT "m".*
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM "table" WHERE "column" = 'value' FOR UPDATE
) "m"
FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY
```

But in oracle it throws ORA-00907 - MISSING RIGHT PARENTHESIS.

I do not have access to the outer/whole query so I cannot simply write the query without the subquery.

So how can I make a "FROM" subquery work with "FOR UPDATE".

Answer (score 2):

The [documented syntax for a `SELECT` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) is:

> ## select::=
>
> [image: Select syntax]

As such, the `FOR UPDATE` clause **MUST** be applied to the outer-most sub-query and **MUST** be the last clause of the statement.

So, to answer your question:

> So how can I make a "FROM" subquery work with "FOR UPDATE".

The answer is that it is impossible to make it work as the syntax does not allow it.

If you want to make it work then:

```sql
SELECT "m".*
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM "table" WHERE "column" = 'value'
) "m"
FOR UPDATE;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=252282c060bf01fe91eff49bfa4bd47a)*

Comment: Thanks. I was expecting an alternative to lock the  subquery, not necessarily  with the "for update" syntax.

Comment: @HugoK See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775960/ Your options appear to be to use `FOR UPDATE` or to lock the entire table.

Comment: **Another caution**. You included `fetch first 2 rows only` but did not include an `order by`. The result of this is that you will get any 2 random rows that satisfy your other conditions. Without `order by` the DBMS is free to return results in any order what-so-ever.